# unable to run a python file because of Module not found error despite sourcing the pythonpath

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, ros

I have been trying to run a python file using rosrun command but unfortunately I am having this module not found error because of a package named rospkg. Until a day before yesterday, it was all working fine but yesterday, ubuntu18.04 has got some updates out of which an update for ubuntu base was also present, since that update I am having this error.

I have tried to check whether I have installed the respective python-rospkg and its says I already have the latest version. I have also using 
   `echo $PYTHONPATH` 
to check the sourced paths and they are sourced correct, I am not sure whats causing this error.

the error is as follows 
      `Traceback (most recent call last
        File 
       "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/control.py", 
       line 5, in <module>
       import roslib
       File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist- 
       packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
        from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
       File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist- 
       packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
       import rospkg
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospkg'`

The shebang for my is as follows,
      `#!/usr/bin/python3`
When i try to run the file by changing the shebang to 
      `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`
I get the following error 
       `Traceback (most recent call last):
        File 
        "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/control.py", 
         line 3, in <module>
         import tensorflow as tf
         ImportError: No module named tensorflow`

I have installed tensorflow version 1.14 using pip installation. Can anyone please help me solving this error. Thanks in advance

edit:

I have manually tried to set the python path to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` as when I tried to install python-rospkg, it says the its already instaled in that location. Doing that I am having error importing tensorflow and the error is

```
 `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
 "/home/microbot/catkin_ws/src/spider/spider_control/control.py", line 
  3, in <module>
 import tensorflow as tf
 File "/home/microbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
 import inspect as _inspect
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 41, in <module>
 import linecache
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
 import tokenize
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 33, in <module>
 import re
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'
Error in sys.excepthook:`
```

Comment: Switching between Python 2 and Python 3 like that is absolutely certainly going to fail; they are two different languages. As your project is apparently written for Python 2 that's what you should use. It looks like you have simply not installed Tensorflow for Python 2.

Comment: oh thanks for the heads up.  but it was working all fine till the night before that. Although I agree, I have mentioned python3 in the shebang and  the ros uses python2.7 to compile most of its important packages. I re-installed python3-ros packages and now that error is not there anymore.